# sp2013 search results mouseover = Windows challenge

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

I've got a SP2013 Search Service Application, along with an Enterprise Search site collection.

When searching for something with results from this content source, mousing over the results immediately brings up a Windows challenge. The Windows challenge indicates the challege is originating from the search server itself, not the server where the search results are at.

As I mouse over each search result title, if I have not yet moused over it, I get the challenge. If I ignore the challenge, I can mouse over that particular title again without additional challenges.

If I do click a title, I am again challenged. I put in my creds, and see the target search results page, but am again prompted for creds from the search server. I put in my creds, and one more time am prompted for creds from the search server. In the Windows challenge box, clicking "Remember my password" has no effect.

Any thoughts on what is causing this, or what I can do to remedy the situation?

This phenomena occurs with search results from both SharePoint and non-SharePoint sites. All IIS instances involved are config'd to use NTLM, and have Integrated Windows Auth activated. Browser is IE8, and our entire intranet domain is added to the "Local Intranet" security zone. Servers are W2k8 or W2k3. Our IE users have "Automatic Login only in Intranet zone" checked. There is no SSL in use in this scenario.

Comment: Certificate warning or http? I would say the authentication does not work properly maybe because of trust. Have you tried moving the domain into trusted zone?

Comment: In our environment, we have "Automatic login in local intranet zone" config'd in IE. I should have added in that bit (will edit original). There is no SSL in use in this scenario.

Comment: Use fiddler to see whether the NTLM header is passed or not.

Comment: I did just now try with Fiddler to see. I visit the intro page of Enterprise Search, and the first two entries show "WWW-Authenticate header is present: NTLM", and the third entry says "No WWW-Authenticate header is present". There is no challenge yet. I put in a search term, and... while I am typing the search term, I get a challenge. Over in Fiddler, I see three new lines, all aimed at /_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery and all thres say "WWW-Authenticate header is present: NTLM". In both 3-row exchanges, the second row contains extended NTLM information.

Comment: I did find this, which did get the problem to go away: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ff191f26-a467-4103-a09a-6f0fe2012d50/vtibinclientsvcprocessquery-post-401?forum=sharepointadmin The problem was, I needed to enable Anonymous Authentication for the /_vti_bin/ folder in IIS.

Comment: glad you solved it! Do you know why the authentication was changed for that folder?